# IPC between VsCode extension and C++ program?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ipc, vscode-extensions

My goal is to send data to a windows application written in C++ from a VsCode extension.
I have read about IPC on windows, and it looks like a shared memory approach might be the simplest for ipc between two C++ applications, as described here:

`https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/memory/creating-named-shared-memory?redirectedfrom=MSDN`

I also read about the possibility of writing COM clients/servers, but it seems very complicated.

However when it comes to IPC between VsCode extensions (written in javascript) and C++ programs, I'm not sure how that can be done.

Comment: do you really consider writing COM stuff? Have you considered sockets?

Comment: @rioV8 I don't really mind having to learn a bit of COM, but I would prefer a simple solution. Shared memory seems simpler than sockets but I don't really know since I've never written anything with sockets. I just don't know the best option when it comes to VsCode extensions communicating with native C++.

Comment: sockets is much much much simpler than COM. Getting COM in JavaScript is most likely impossible, how do you think Ajax works

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for a sockets library?

Comment: Make a simple Ajax interface (support http on port 80) on the C++ side, HTTP is simple text in and simple text out, you don't need to support many headers

Comment: gRPC or other RPC protocols (like JSON-RPC) are much simpler to go than shared memory or COM.